# How do you get the Firefox Auto-Refresh to hold off when you're entering text?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, reloadevery

I'm using Firefox with the Auto-Refresh add-in to read all the SO-family sites, but everytime I'm trying to type a question or answer it refreshes and makes me start over.  Is there some setting I can use so that it's more intelligent about it, or do I just have to disable the add-in every time?

**Edit:** [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115)

Comment: Link to the add-on so we know which one you're talking about

Comment: Probably ReloadEvery, I have the same problem! Especially on twitter.com it sometimes refreshes mid-sentence :P

Comment: Follow the reloadevery tag to the other question to see what happened there... http://superuser.com/questions/13235/ip-address-spoofed-how-to-fix

Comment: Thanks, I have mine set for 1 minute, hopefully that doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to disable it every time you want to type something up and not lose it from a refresh.

That is unless the project updates their add-on to detect if you're typing in a text field, or if you yourself go in and fix up the source code for that update.

Other than that, type fast or just switch it off when you're on a single question page.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have JavaScript enabled?  You should see an alertbox whenever you try to refresh the page.  That won't happen for comments, though.

Maybe using another add-on in addition to AutoRefresh could solve the problem.  I know Tab Mix Plus and ReloadEvery can't do domain-wide automatic page refreshing, but you can enable it for individual tabs.  Disabling refresh for a tab when you're writing a response can override the other extension.

Edit: I can't find any trace of an AutoRefresh plugin.  Are you using [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/22846) Greasemonkey script enabled for the domain?