# How to have a timer driven "reload" of a tab in Mac OS X Safari 4?

Tags: macos, browser-addons, safari

Is there a way to have safari 4 on Mac OS X to reload a web page every N minutes on a per tab basis?

Comment: Use Safari 4 to download FireFox. Use FireFox to install the autoreload extension.

Comment: @TheTXI: BOOOO! (That will have to suffice without comment downvoting.)

Comment: Is someone trying to cheat on their woot!/enthusiast badge? ;-)

Comment: @TheTXI: of course this is not a solution...

Answer (score 3):

Just use a bookmarklet(a chunk of JavaScript that you can add to your bookmarks). Here's one that I found ages ago and it's served me well:

```
javascript:(function(p){open('','',p).document.write('%3Cbody%20id=1%3E%3Cnobr%20id=2%3E%3C/nobr%3E%3Chr%3E%3Cnobr%20id=3%3E%3C/nobr%3E%3Chr%3E%3Ca%20href=%22#%22onclick=%22return!(c=t)%22%3EForce%3C/a%3E%3Cscript%3Efunction%20i(n){return%20d.getElementById(n)}function%20z(){c+=0.2;if(c%3E=t){c=0;e.location=u;r++}x()}function%20x(){s=t-Math.floor(c);m=Math.floor(s/60);s-=m*60;i(1).style.backgroundColor=(r==0||c/t%3E2/3?%22fcc%22:c/t%3C1/3?%22cfc%22:%22ffc%22);i(2).innerHTML=%22Reloads:%20%22+r;i(3).innerHTML=%22Time:%20%22+m+%22:%22+(s%3C10?%220%22+s:s)}c=r=0;d=document;e=opener.top;u=prompt(%22URL%22,e.location.href);t=u?prompt(%22Seconds%22,60):0;setInterval(%22z()%22,200);if(!t){window.close()}%3C/script%3E%3C/body%3E')})('status=0,scrollbars=0,width=100,height=115,left=1,top=1')
```

And here's an edited version of this bookmarklet that removes the URL prompt and just uses the URL of the current tab:

```
javascript:(function(p){open('','',p).document.write('%3Cbody%20id=1%3E%3Cnobr%20id=2%3E%3C/nobr%3E%3Chr%3E%3Cnobr%20id=3%3E%3C/nobr%3E%3Chr%3E%3Ca%20href=%22#%22onclick=%22return!(c=t)%22%3EForce%3C/a%3E%3Cscript%3Efunction%20i(n){return%20d.getElementById(n)}function%20z(){c+=0.2;if(c%3E=t){c=0;e.location=u;r++}x()}function%20x(){s=t-Math.floor(c);m=Math.floor(s/60);s-=m*60;i(1).style.backgroundColor=(r==0||c/t%3E2/3?%22fcc%22:c/t%3C1/3?%22cfc%22:%22ffc%22);i(2).innerHTML=%22Reloads:%20%22+r;i(3).innerHTML=%22Time:%20%22+m+%22:%22+(s%3C10?%220%22+s:s)}c=r=0;d=document;e=opener.top;u=e.location.href;t=u?prompt(%22Seconds%22,60):0;setInterval(%22z()%22,200);if(!t){window.close()}%3C/script%3E%3C/body%3E')})('status=0,scrollbars=0,width=100,height=115,left=1,top=1')
```

Comment: Uhm, nice trick.
   It opens in a new tab the counter. It works, but the additional tab opened is quite annoying, is it possible to avoid its creation and do it all in a single tab? +1 for your answer

Comment: The bookmarklet tries to open a tiny window to manage reloading (that's easier to hide than a tab). Do you have any Safari addons that could be forcing it into a tab? The bookmarklet has to maintain a presence somewhere, because when a page is reloaded any JavaScript that's running on it is destroyed as well. One could write a bookmarklet that embeds the page in an iframe, but that would be replicating the functionality of a site like PAGE REBOOT (mentioned by nik).

Comment: yes, used tinkertool

Answer (score 1):

[Safari Page Monitor](http://pimpmysafari.com/plugins/safari-page-monitor).

> This configurable AppleScript keeps an eye on one or more web pages through Safari, reloading them at specified intervals and reporting any changes it detects, both verbally and through a session log file.
>
> The developer explains “I wrote this script to keep tabs on my brother’s home page after they had had their first baby and started posting pictures. I remembered a page-monitoring feature in the Classic version of Internet Explorer and decided Safari needed something comparable”.

---

That link does not seem to work these days...
There is an [**on-line alternative**](http://pagereboot.com/) (unless you want to write the plugin again).

---

Just [be careful **how and where** you use this](https://superuser.com/questions/13235/ip-address-spoofed-how-to-fix/13236#13236).

Comment: I already had found it googling, but I wasn't able to find a place where to download it ... everything I found leads to the unavailable main site of the author ;(

Answer (score 1):

You can use an AppleScript to do this. Here’s how to reload every open tab every 5 seconds:

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat
        repeat with aTab in (every tab of every window)
            set URL of aTab to (URL of aTab)
        end repeat
        delay 5
    end repeat
end tell
```

You can do some filtering inside the `repeat with aTab` block to only refresh certain tabs (predicated on the URL, title, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you've upgraded to Safari 5 in the meantime, Apple added browser extensions. I made one that does just what you asked.

You can take a look at it here:
[Auto Refresh](http://agriffindesign.com/downloads/autorefresh)

> Use Auto Refresh to set Safari to automatically reload on its own.
>   Perfect for web development and monitoring online auctions,
>   announcements and news.